# VsCode Chrome Debug extension won't work, even after stripping app to 2 files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am on Windows 10. I was having no luck getting an Angular2 app working with VsCode Chrome debugging extension. I stripped the app down to a non-Angular app with just 2 files, but still no progress.

My breakpoints don't get hit and I still get the Error: Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222)"

These are my current two source files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>External JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it now</button>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> myFunction is stored in an external file called "myScript.js".</p>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

MyScript.js

```
function myFunction() { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed."; }
```

My launch.json file contains:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I start lite-server in a command window. As soon as I start it, a tab opens inside IE which happened to be already running. Inside the address bar is "http://localhost:3000/"  The app runs fine. (What exactly is making this connection to IE? Could this conflict with the Chrome extension?)

I close out the IE tab and then go to Debug in VsCode. I set the configuration to "Launch Chrome against localhost...". I press F5 to start debugging. It opens a Chrome window and browses to "localhost:3000".

The app runs fine but my breakpoints don't get hit and I get an error in VSCode: "Error: Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222)"

It seems to be trying to use the 3rd configuration "Attach to Chrome...". But the dropdown  was set to the second "Launch Chrome ...". I also make sure any running copies of Chrome are killed before hit F5.

I should also mention that I can create a node.js app in VsCode and the breakpoints work fine because of the built-in support.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Chrome shortcut, and select properties In the "target" field, append `--remote-debugging-port=9222` or in a command prompt, execute `/chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`.

Answer (score 0):

### request:launch works

I have this `launch.json` and a breakpoint works with `F5` in `VSCode` starting a new Chrome instance. I even do not have to close the other Chrome instance:

```
    {
    "name": "launch localhost",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/public/calc.html",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot:rest-test}"
            },
```